# Symfony 2 : children class

Tags: php, class, symfony

I am trying to work with 2 classes: `Activity` and `Mandate`. A `Mandate` is an `Activity` (so a children)

I want to erase a mandate by clicking on a link with the mandate's ID.

So here's my action :

```
public function eraseAction($id = null)
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    if (isset($id)) 
    {
        // existing user edition : let's load its data
        $mandate = $em->find('MyAppToolsBundle:Activity', $id);

        if (!$mandate)
        {
            $message = 'Error while deleting the record';
        }
        else
        {
        $mandate->setErase(true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'erreur';
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('MyAppToolsBundle:Admin:mandate.html.twig',array(
    'message' => $message));    
}
```

My problem is that I can only search my Mandate with his parent Activity (cause I don't have the attribute ID in Mandate) But the method setErase is only for a mandate, so I have an error..

I must search the mandate by looking for in Activity, but then I can't use the method that I have only created on the Mandate class.

Here's my class Activity :

```
   <?php
    namespace MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Activity
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Hour", mappedBy="activity")
         */
         protected $hour;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string",length="255")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\MinLength(2)
         */    
        private $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string",length="20")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         */    
        private $color;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * Set color
         *
         * @param string $color
         */
        public function setColor($color)
        {
            $this->color = $color;
        }

        /**
         * Get color
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getColor()
        {
            return $this->color;
        }
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->hours = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Add hours
         *
         * @param Furter\OutilGestionBundle\Entity\Hour $hours
         */
        public function addHour(\MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Hour $hours)
        {
            $this->hours[] = $hours;
        }

        /**
         * Get hours
         *
         * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getHours()
        {
            return $this->hours;
        }

        /**
         * Get hour
         *
         * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getHour()
        {
            return $this->hour;
        }
    }
```

And my Mandate class :

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mandate extends Activity
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="date")
    */
    private $startdate;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="date")
    */
    private $enddate;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
    */
    private $erase = 0;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Hour", mappedBy="activity")
     */
     protected $hour;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Client")
     */
    private $client;


    /**
     * Set startdate
     *
     * @param date $startdate
     */
    public function setStartdate($startdate)
    {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }

    /**
     * Get startdate
     *
     * @return date 
     */
    public function getStartdate()
    {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    /**
     * Set enddate
     *
     * @param date $enddate
     */
    public function setEnddate($enddate)
    {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;
    }

    /**
     * Get enddate
     *
     * @return date 
     */
    public function getEnddate()
    {
        return $this->enddate;
    }
    /**
     * @var MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Hour
     */
    private $hours;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hours = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add hours
     *
     * @param MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Hour $hours
     */
    public function addHour(\MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Hour $hours)
    {
        $this->hours[] = $hours;
    }

    /**
     * Get hours
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getHours()
    {
        return $this->hours;
    }

    /**
     * Get hour
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getHour()
    {
        return $this->hour;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Client $client
     */
    public function setClient(\MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return MyApp\ToolsBundle\Entity\Client 
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Set erase
     *
     * @param boolean $erase
     */
    public function setErase($erase)
    {
        $this->erase = $erase;
    }

    /**
     * Get erase
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getErase()
    {
        return $this->erase;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you forgot a word in your post. I added a placeholder in it. Replace it with the missing word, or with nothing if you did not forget anything.

Comment: Have you tried to use a repository instead of the entity manager? Like this : `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyAppMyBybundle:Mandate')->find("$id")`

Comment: Thx for your anwser, it does the same : "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'".
The weird part is that i got the id on my table, but not on my entity so he make an error.
Should I have an attribute "id" in mandate ?

Comment: I don't know... By the way, you're using class table inheritance, aren't you?

Comment: That must be it, I don't use it... (what a noob) I thought if I was doing like a standard object programming it was "alright". I just did an extends (I took for example when I did this with FOSUser)

I just read the official doctrine doc. I don't understand everything, specialy the schema.yml. Do you use modifiy it ? Or you do it all in php and get it generate ? I'll edit my 2 entity

Comment: I didn't get your two last questions. Why don't we move this discussion to chat? I'm french, so that could be easier for both of us... I'll be available tomorrow at 10 a.m.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help ! I finaly find my problem !

I didn't know you had to put `@MappedSuperclass` on the superclass instead of Entity !

It's working !!!

What a day !